# Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, android-volley

**Problem statement:**

I am trying to access an REST API that will return a JSON object for various HTTP status codes (400, 403, 200 etc) using Volley.

For any HTTP status other than 200, it seems the 'Unexpected response code 400' is a problem. Does anyone have a way to bypass this 'error'?

**Code:**

```
protected void getLogin() {   
    final String mURL = "https://somesite.com/api/login";

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    // Post params to be sent to the server
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("username", username.getText().toString());
    params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(mURL, new JSONObject(
            params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject obj = response
                        .getJSONObject("some_json_obj");

                Log.w("myApp",
                        "status code..." + obj.getString("name"));

                // VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.w("error in response", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: I had the character "é" in my query string. Worked after I encoded all my parameters.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

One way of doing this without changing `Volley`'s source code is to check for the response data in the `VolleyError` and parse it your self.

As of [`f605da3 commit`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/f605da3d9e6590351cb0bb26bb6ba5146952777c), `Volley` throws a [`ServerError` exception](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/f605da3d9e6590351cb0bb26bb6ba5146952777c/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#162) that contains the raw network response.

So you can do something similar to this in your error listener:

```
/* import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser; */
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    // As of f605da3 the following should work
    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
    if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
        try {
            String res = new String(response.data,
                       HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // returned data is not JSONObject?
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For future, if `Volley` changes, one can follow the above approach where you need to check the `VolleyError` for raw data that has been sent by the server and parse it.

I hope that they implement that `TODO` mentioned in the [source file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/f605da3d9e6590351cb0bb26bb6ba5146952777c/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java#162).

Answer (score 15):

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```

You need to add Content-Type to the header.

Comment: sending get request. api working fine but getting BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500.

Comment: @HemsLodha 500 - Internal Server Error
"A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable" It's problem on server.

Comment: Encountered similar error, but mine was "Unexpected response code 415". I had Content-Type application/json, but after adding charset=utf-8, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 11):

Me too got the same error but in my case I was calling **url** with blank spaces.

Then, I fixed it by parsing like below.

```
String url = "Your URL Link";

url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                ...
                                ...
                                ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This solve my issue in Android 4.4.2

Comment: This is a great answer. In new versions, the code was working ok, but older versions this has taken me for a big rollercoaster drive. Never expected that Android being based on Linux / Unix was not taking care of this earlier. Thank you @Rasool Mohamed

Answer (score 9):

Try this ...

```
 StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(type,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            // valid response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // error
        }
    }){

@Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("grant_type", "password");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // Removed this line if you dont need it or Use application/json
        // params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean that want to get status codes?

`VolleyError` has a member variable type of `NetworkResponse` and it is public.

You can access `error.networkResponse.statusCode` for http error code.

I hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was append an extra '/' to my url, *e.g.*:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com"
```

to

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: It is easy to miss the forward slash, and this helped direct me to find my mistake. Incorrect url being passed was issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was not writing reg_url with :8080 .
String reg_url = "http://192.168.29.163:8080/register.php";

Comment: then what is solution for this

Answer (score 0):

change

> public static final String URL = "http://api-Location";

to

> public static final String URL = "https://api-Location"

it's happen because i'm using 000webhostapp app

Answer (score -2):

Just to update all, after some deliberations, I have decided to use Async Http Client instead to solve my earlier problem. The library allows a cleaner approach (*to me*) to manipulate HTTP responses especially in cases where JSON objects are returned in all scenarios/HTTP statuses.

```
protected void getLogin() {

    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username); 
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password); 

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("username", username.getText().toString());
    params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

    RestClient.post(getHost() + "api/v1/auth/login", params,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                JSONObject response) {

            try {

                //process JSONObject obj 
                Log.w("myapp","success status code..." + statusCode);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
                Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            Log.w("myapp", "failure status code..." + statusCode);


            try {
                //process JSONObject obj
                Log.w("myapp", "error ..."  + errorResponse.getString("message").toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should consider selecting answer of `listboss` as correct. It is the answer to your question, therefore with a reason it has highest points. Using another library is not a valid answer.