# Android Volley error while posting data to server

Tags: java, android, android-volley

[here is the api response which works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuVZC.jpg) While posting data to the server I'm getting server volley error as response code but at the same time remaining API working fine.

[image]

Comment: Hello, you can check this link: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505485/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-404)

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: before sending volley request try to print the url and copy the url and paste it in browser to check whether the url you are sending is correct and get exeuting correctly

Comment: The typical trigger for an error 404 message is when website content has been removed or moved to another URL. First Check your URL either its working or not

Comment: Are you doing a string request or are you trying a json request?

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP 404` ordinary means "page not found" ...

host-name [mydrivinglession.co.uk](https://www.mydrivinglession.co.uk/final-service-api/?action=list_my_service) cannot even be resolved in `DNS`:

```
$ traceroute mydrivinglession.co.uk
mydrivinglession.co.uk: Name or service not known
```

... nor is it registered with `co.uk`

> mydrivinglession.co.uk is available!

guess you would have to remove `mydrivinglession.co.uk` from your local `hosts` file... that most likely the only reason why the response, which you claim would be "working", appears to be "working".

one might want to establish a **publicly available API**, before attempting to perform requests... because your requests might run against a fantasy domain in the clouds, which nobody knows.