# Android can not send post request with volley(BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404)

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I am trying to send some info to my api with post method(volley), but keep getting errors. Most consistent and the latest one is

E/Volley: [1449] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://....
D/Error.Response: com.android.volley.ClientError

I am able to post it with postman but not in android. I am sure nothing is wrong in the other side. I don't know what to do.

I have tried several implementations with getheader(),getBodyContentType(), Json object, string, parsing, try catch and so on..

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "....";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response

                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", "test@email.com");
            params.put("token", "token");

            return params;
        }

    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Volley BasicNetwork.performRequest() unexpected response code 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505485/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-404)

Comment: 404 means not found, 401 means forbidden, you are probably sending your methods an incorrect URI.. Have you tried communicating with an insecure version of your API to make sure you are contacting the right endpoint? Have you tried RetroFit? Can you perform a GET request on the same API and get a 200 OK? Do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Have you tried contacting your API with curl to see what the `content-type` is?

Comment: Checked the URI, deleted the [Authorize], have not tried get request.Endpoint was fine, but removed the getParams() and implemented something different without a method(getParams) and I was able to write it to database through api. returnin 200 OK but also gave me an error code 500. Don't want to use retrofit, so I will go back to using loopj. Other things you said were also checked and nothing wrong. Thanks for your replies.