# Pie volley connection

Tags: android, android-volley

Android volley is not working in pie i already used  two type of methods to solve this http problem.

manifest

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: add stacktrace.

Comment: you mean try catch?

Comment: add your logcat errors

Comment: E/Volley: [19988] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion.<init>(ProtocolVersion.java:6) at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:148) at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97) at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:118)

Comment: solution is here https://github.com/google/volley/issues/235#issuecomment-450527549

Comment: i already tried those methods but its not working

Comment: Now its showing  E/Volley: [592] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for " url"

Comment: no it showing the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39505882/5773037

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

xml

```
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
        <certificates src="user" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```