# Web API with POST operation throws 404 error in Android

Tags: android

My API works fine in Postman. However in my Android app it gives the following error:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404
com.android.volley.ClientError at 
com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:199) at 
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131) at
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

My complete and minimal sample that demonstrates the error:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
params.put("login_id",id); params.put("password",pass); 
CustomRequest jsonObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,Url.Login,params,new 
Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { 
    @Override public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
        Log.d("res", response.toString());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to add the api description along with the volley code that you have,

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505485/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-404

Comment: Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("login_id",id);
        params.put("password",pass);

        CustomRequest jsonObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,Url.Login,params,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Log.d("res", response.toString());