# Android Volley : Supported status codes issue

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

I have used a restful API in my android application with the [volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) library, as I know in restful API we should implement [STATUS CODES](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) in special situation, but as I checked volley codes in this path : `volley\toolbox\BasicNetwork.java` I see volley only accepts status codes between 200 and 299.

```
if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Why? 
Does this mean volley does not support RESTFUL architectural?

Comment: What do you mean? Volley implements other kind of codes like 300, 400, 500 and so on.

Comment: i don't think so, because when i send 400 status code from server, i getting this exception BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

Comment: I think that you must use VolleyError class. I will put it an answer

Comment: volleyError callback in onError method is null!

Answer (score 0):

VolleyError has a variable of type NetworkResponse that is public. You can access error.networkResponse.statusCode to implement your http error codes.

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
    try {    
        // Deserialize data using what you want
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

You can read more about this here. [Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)

Answer (score 0):

If the server `STATUS_CODE` is in between 200 - 299 it is considerably a success status and `Volley` will fire the `onResponse` callback.

The code:

```
if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Just simply means: When the status code **IS NOT IN BETWEEN 200 - 299** therefore it is an error and Volley will fire the `onErrorResponse` callback instead.