# Volley error: Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, android-volley

I use below code to get Volley request and get json:

```
  JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                service_address , null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    parseJsonFeed(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }){


            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Removed this line if you dont need it or Use application/json
                // params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
```

but after running it gives me this error in `logcat`:

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400
```

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400), but it will not help me. I'm so confused whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried sending a request from another source like https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal I used this service before without Volley and it worked fine

Comment: @DennisvanOpstal i test my address in  hurl.it and it gives me 404! i'm so tired of struggling

Comment: There probably should be an error message with the 404, if so, what does it say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is of any help, but here is how I use Volley for my Login request:

```
/**
 * Method that checks given user credentials with the ones in the online DB
 * @param v the view that activated this method
 */
public void logIn(View v) {
    final String email = String.valueOf(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail)).getText());
    final String password = String.valueOf(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPassword)).getText());

    String tag_string_req = "string_req";
    final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();
    String url = "http://android.diggin.io/diggin/v1/login";
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response);
            try {
                final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (!jsonObject.getBoolean("error")) {
                    apiKey = jsonObject.getString("apiKey");
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.apiKey), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putString(getString(R.string.apiKey), apiKey);
                    editor.commit();
                    refreshApiKey();
                } else {
                    //Send message when something goes wrong
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                            try {
                                dlgAlert.setMessage(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                dlgAlert.setMessage("Something went wrong, please try again");
                            }
                            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                            dlgAlert.create().show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //Send message when something goes wrong
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
                    dlgAlert.setMessage("Error while logging in, please try again");
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                    dlgAlert.create().show();
                }
            });
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: my service work well with your code but it doesn't work with this site  hurl.it !what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you filled in all parameters and headers right, otherwise you can check the error from the site, most of the times it says where it goes wrong

Comment: please check below answer