# Error Android Volley Unexpected response code 400

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i am using volley for a get data function but i get unexpected response code 400 for http.
 Below i have pasted my code

```
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("loi", "" + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("loi", "" + error);
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    int size = SupportData.vtvlist.get(stt).getmPostArrayList().size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        name = SupportData.vtvlist.get(stt).getmPostArrayList().get(i).getNamepost().toString();
                        value = SupportData.vtvlist.get(stt).getmPostArrayList().get(i).getValue().toString();
                        params.put(""+name,value);
                    }

                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(sr);
```

Is there anyone who can tell me where I am doing wrong in my code? Any help is appreciable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)

Comment: no .It is another question

Comment: are you using post or get method or any other one

Comment: 400 status code is for `Bad Request` check if you are passing valid URL.

Comment: try changing `Request.Method.PUT` to `Request.Method.GET` inside `StringRequest()`

Comment: yeah. My URL is valid.

Comment: @Mohammed yeah. i change to Request.Method.POST . thank u

Comment: did it worked?? if worked then accept my answer below

Comment: Use Request.Method.POST  and if u have any parameters such as username or password pass it in the params.put("key",key value); if not do not pass anything and also remove params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); from there and see if it is working or not.

Comment: @krishank Tripathi. yeah. exactly.

Comment: see this if you have nay issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing `Request.Method.PUT` to `Request.Method.POST` since you are trying to get data with StringRequest.