# Read String Value from JSON Object and show Toast Message

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-toast

I am using `Volley` in my application.After making `JSONObject` `POST` request I get JSONObject in response if user is found.If user is not found I get one message as user not found.I want to display `Toast` message if user is not found after parsing the JSONObject.
This is response If user is found

```
{
        "name": ABC,
        "address": Pune,
        "status": "Married"
}
```

This is response If user not found

```
{
        "message":"User not Found"
}
```

This is my `JSONObject` POST request

```
JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String error=response.getString("message");
                        if(error.equals("User not Found")){
                            coolToast.make("User Not Found",CoolToast.INFO);
                            coolToast.setDuration(CoolToast.SHORT);
                        }
                         else{
                            coolToast.make("User Found",CoolToast.SUCCESS);
                            coolToast.setDuration(CoolToast.SHORT);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            })
```

How to display Toast after reading the message from JSONObject ?

Comment: you are already implementing toast, so what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: After user is not found, and reading String Toast is not displayed.Something wrong in Parsing ?

Comment: You forgot to write show() method of Toast. Write coolToast.show()

Comment: can you add your response

Comment: You are trying to read message key from response, but in your success response you do not have 'message' key. You might wanna check your catch block. or use debugger to check you code flow

Comment: @Satyam like AIK said you forgot to write show() or you should add log here too.

Comment: I have used one Library for showing toast, this is the way CoolToast is displayed.

Comment: can you provide the library docs link here?

Comment: [CoolToast](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6116)

Comment: I think you should reconsider Arshad's comment above.

Comment: When user is found this is Log I am getting `{
        "name": ABC,
        "address": Pune,
        "status": "Married"
}`  otherwise I get    `E/Volley: [36026] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://192.168.100.89:9500/api/finduser/`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400

Answer (score 1):

After creating Toast you need to add show() method of Toast. In your case add coolToast.show().

Thanks.

Comment: read the comments first he is using a library i thought the same but that's not the way to show the toast in that library.

Answer (score 0):

Inside try block(first line) you are trying to access key message which is not available for success response, on that case you get JSONException (catch block).

First use `.has(key)` to check if key exists.

Inside response first check if name exists

```
if(response.has("name"){
//User found
}else{
//User not found
//now access message here as response.getString("message")
}
```

Comment: using the same approach how to check for JSONObject existence at same time ?

Comment: If your service returns invalid JSONObject you will get error inside error callback (onErrorResponse).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the same code structure you may use

```
String error=response.optString("message");
```

instead of

```
String error=response.getString("message");
```