# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400,marker doesnt show up

Tags: android, android-volley

problem : after click on search the marker doesn't show up again and give me error response code 400 for ( link )

logcat error

```
E/Response:: [{"lat":"-7.552991","lng":"110.798546","id":"13","nama":"SMK 4 NEGERI SURAKARTA"}]
E/Volley: [4208] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://tugasupload.esy.es/api/maps.php?latitude=SMK 4 NEGERI SURAKARTA
```

and source code

```
 private void getMarkers() {

            System.out.println("abc");
            dialog.setMessage("Mengambil Data");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();


            JsonArrayRequest reqData = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    "http://tugasupload.esy.es/api/maps.php?latitude=" + ambilcari, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                            try {
                                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                                    title = data.getString("nama");
                                                    id = data.getInt("id");
                                                    latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(data.getString(LAT)), Double.parseDouble(data.getString(LNG)));
                                                    lokasi = data.getString("nama");
                                                    // Menambah data marker untuk di tampilkan ke google map

                                                    addMarker(latLng, title, lokasi, id);


                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();


                                            }
                                    }
                                    dialog.cancel();


                            }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Ada Kesalahan Mohon Periksa Kembali", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                    });

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(reqData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            assert imm != null;
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            ambilcari = acTextView.getText().toString();
            lokasi();
            gMap.clear();


    }

    private void lokasi() {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.show();

            String url1 = "http://tugasupload.esy.es/api/lokasi.php?latitude=" + ambilcari;
            url1= url1.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            System.out.println(url1);


            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url1, new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.e("Response: ", response);

                            try {
                                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                            System.out.println(latLng);
                                            lati = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LAT));
                                            longi = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LNG));
                                            if (ambilcari.equals(" ")) {


                                                    center = new LatLng(-7.568737, 110.827062);
                                                    cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(10).build();
                                                    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                                                    getMarkers();
                                            } else {
                                                    center = new LatLng(lati, longi);
                                                    cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(12).build();
                                                    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                                                    getMarkers();
                                            }
                                    }
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // JSON error

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse( VolleyError volleyError ) {
                            try {
                                    String responseBody = new String( volleyError.networkResponse.data, "utf-8" );
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( responseBody );
                            } catch ( JSONException e ) {
                                    //Handle a malformed json response
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored){

                            }
                    }
            }
            );

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }
```

and i am trying to solve this case by following :
[Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)

and adding `url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");` before adding this code after search, force close app

Comment: What do you get in `System.out.println(url1);` when you add `url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")`?

Comment: only latling like this  "lat/lng: (-7.563838,110.830705)
    abc", cmiiw, sry

Comment: I meant what does your `url1` look like at the `System.out.println(url1);` line. It should print the actual url in the logs

Comment: like this  "http://tugasupload.esy.es/api/lokasi.php?nama=SMK 3 NEGERI SURAKARTA"

Comment: still looking for answer

Comment: I think that's where the problem is. Your url should look like `tugasupload.esy.es/api/lokasi.php?nama=SMK%203%20NEGERI%20SURAKARTA`

Comment: so, u mean the wrong is in file php?

Comment: No. I mean the request url that you are sending is wrong

Comment: how to fix it ? can u give some example, thank  you

Comment: what happens when you add `url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");`? can you add logs for that since that is the solution

Comment: after give this code url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); , app running fine and can search location but the marker doesnt show up again,  ok i try it

Comment: i try it, but always like this  6 E/Volley: [85205] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://arizalway.000webhostapp.com/api/lokasi.php?namasekolah=SMK 4 NEGERI SURAKARTA