# facebook graph api making the app scrape the url automatically android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

iam trying to make facebook **scrape** my url automatically when i share it
instead of making it manually by this page

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

and i used volley to achieve it

but it didnt work and give me an error

so the code is

```
String fbLink = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, fbLink,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", Link);
            params.put("scrape", "true");
            params.put("access_token", "53423443434234534");

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

and the error which come is

```
 E/Volley: [819] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://graph.facebook.com/
```

updated

the error is

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"DNqMWPkaAy5"}}
```

updated 2

fixed wwhen i knew the error it was because of the access token

here is the topic that helped me

[Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)
thank u

Comment: what´s the point of scraping it right when you share it? maybe you are trying to do something you could do in a better way?

Comment: iam using facebook applinks to share my links to facebook .. i mean my users links like ... www.example.com/users/index.php?=userid ... and make the people go to my app when then open it from facebook browser but the problem is its not working until i scrap it

Comment: what means "not working"? it should work, and i don´t think scraping a link before sharing is a good solution.

Comment: thank u for your response 
but it did and worked when i scraped it and i fixed it 
so could u tell me why its not a good solution

Comment: i know that it worked, but that does not mean it´s a good solution ;) - i can only help you if you tell me what you mean with "not working". that´s not a description we can work with.

Comment: thank u .. the problem was when i was adding the url to facebook .. if i tried to open it by mobile it was open it as a url in the facebook browser not sending the person to my app .. so when i was scrap the url it was send the person or the user to the android app or playstore url

Answer (score 0):

fixed wwhen i knew the error it was because of the access token

here is the topic that helped me

[Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)