# Android Studio: Transparent checkout using Mercado Pago

Tags: android, mercadopago

I am trying to implement for the first time the Mercado Pago's transparent checkout in Android.

I've already downloaded the newest version of the SDK provided in https://github.com/mercadopago/px-android and executed it normally in the Emulator.

In the GitHub page mentioned above, we have an explanation of how to implement Mercado Pago's checkout with just one line of code:

```
new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder("public_key", "checkout_preference_id")
    .build()
    .startPayment(activityOrContext, requestCode);
```

Where `public_key` we can get in the credentials webpage. But the **String** `checkout_preference_id` I have no idea of how to create it, even though they showed how to create it at the end of the GitHub webpage.

**Create your preference id**

```
curl -X POST \
     'https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{
           "items": [
               {
               "title": "Dummy Item",
               "description": "Multicolor Item",
               "quantity": 1,
               "currency_id": "ARS",
               "unit_price": 10.0
               }
           ],
           "payer": {
               "email": "payer@email.com"
           }
     }'
```

I tried to put a random **String** in `checkout_preference_id`, but it did not work. Only the **String** in the example app of Mercado Pago worked.

```
private static final String DUMMY_PREFERENCE_ID = "243962506-0bb62e22-5c7b-425e-a0a6-c22d0f4758a9";
```

All the other ways of implementing it presented in the example app of Mercado Pago require a fake confirmation of payment.

I appreciate if anyone could show some code of how to create and pass the variable `checkout_preference_id` into the main command of Mercado Pago payment.

**EDIT**

I also appreciate if anyone could give us an example of a **Not fake** confirmation of payment with some code.

I guess `checkout_preference_id` can be accessed via a Marketplace website or maybe creating a `curl` using Android's webservice. Then, it is still a mystery to me.

Concerning to the alternitive way of paying with MercadoPago, we have this other arguments to pass:

```
new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder("public_key", checkoutPreference, paymentConfiguration)
                .build()
                .startPayment(activityOrContext, requestCode);
```

Where `checkoutPreference` allows you to create a **custom item** to sell.

```
final Item item = new Item.Builder("Product Title", 1, new BigDecimal(12.3)).setDescription("Product Description").build();
CheckoutPreference checkoutPreference = new CheckoutPreference.Builder(Sites.BRASIL, "a@a.a", Collections.singletonList(item)).setDefaultInstallments(1).build();
```

`paymentConfiguration` is implemented **the fake confirmation of payment**.

```
PaymentConfiguration paymentConfiguration = new PaymentConfiguration.Builder(new MyPaymentProcessor()).build();
```

Where the class `MyPaymentProcessor()` and the other classes in which it depends on can be found in the GitHub example.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Álysson Alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348524/4300670) helped to understand how to generate the **String** `checkout_preference_id`.

Below you will see the minimum code needed to receive a payment with MercadoPago.

Firstly, you have to add the dependencies in the **build.gradle** (Module: app)

```
// Dealing with HTTP internet connection
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

//Dealing with MercadoPago SDK and dependencies
implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.0.+'
```

Some people recommend to add internet permission in the **Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Next, you need to create a JSONObject and there are different ways of doing that.

This way:

```
    StringBuilder strjsonobj = new StringBuilder();
    String strJson = "{\n" +
            "           \"items\": [\n" +
            "               {\n" +
            "               \"title\": \"Item\",\n" +
            "               \"description\": \"Multicolor Item\",\n" +
            "               \"quantity\": 1,\n" +
            "               \"currency_id\": \"BRL\",\n" +
            "               \"unit_price\": 35.0\n" +
            "               }\n" +
            "           ],\n" +
            "           \"payer\": {\n" +
            "\t\t    \"name\": \"Núbia\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"surname\": \"Macedo\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"email\": \"leann@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"date_created\": \"2015-06-02T12:58:41.425-04:00\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"phone\": {\n" +
            "\t\t      \"area_code\": \"\",\n" +
            "\t\t      \"number\": \"880.402.7555\"\n" +
            "\t\t    },\n" +
            "\t\t    \"identification\": {\n" +
            "\t\t      \"type\": \"DNI\",\n" +
            "\t\t      \"number\": \"123456789\"\n" +
            "\t\t    },\n" +
            "\t\t    \"address\": {\n" +
            "\t\t      \"street_name\": \"Núbia Viela\",\n" +
            "\t\t      \"street_number\": 25598,\n" +
            "\t\t      \"zip_code\": \"8972\"\n" +
            "\t\t    }\n" +
            "\t\t  }\n" +
            "     }";

    strjsonobj.append(strJson);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(strjsonobj.toString());
        Log.i("debinf MainAct", "object is : "+jsonObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or this way:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    final JSONObject itemJSON = new JSONObject();
    final JSONObject payerJSON = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray itemJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {

        itemJSON.put("title", "Dummy Item");
        itemJSON.put("description", "Multicolor Item");
        itemJSON.put("quantity", 1);
        itemJSON.put("currency_id", "BRL");
        itemJSON.put("unit_price", 2.10);

        itemJsonArray.put(itemJSON);

        JSONObject phoneJSON = new JSONObject();
        phoneJSON.put("area_code", "");
        phoneJSON.put("number", "880.402.7555");
        JSONObject idJSON = new JSONObject();
        idJSON.put("type", "DNI");
        idJSON.put("number", "123456789");
        JSONObject addressJSON = new JSONObject();
        addressJSON.put("street_name", "Núbia Viela");
        addressJSON.put("street_number", 25598);
        addressJSON.put("zip_code", "8972");

        payerJSON.put("name", "Núbia");
        payerJSON.put("surname", "Macedo");
        payerJSON.put("email", "leann@gmail.com");
        payerJSON.put("date_created", "2015-06-02T12:58:41.425-04:00");
        payerJSON.put("phone", phoneJSON);
        payerJSON.put("identification", idJSON);
        payerJSON.put("address", addressJSON);


        jsonObject.put("items", itemJsonArray);
        jsonObject.put("payer", payerJSON);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

MercadoPago suggests to send as much information as you can about the payer in order to increase the rate of payment conversion. But you can send as little as shown in the question.

Besides that, you can personalize other things in the JSONObject such as shown [here](https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/payments/web-checkout/personalization/)

Now, let's create the variable **String** `checkout_preference_id`. For that, I used the method `volley`. When the MercadoPago server sends back our variable, we will automatically start the payment.

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    final String url = "https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences?access_token="+ACCESS_TOKEN_SANDBOX;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.i("debinf MainAct", "response JSONObject: "+response);
                String checkoutPreferenceId = response.getString("id");
                new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder(PUBLIC_KEY_SANDBOX, checkoutPreferenceId).build().startPayment(MainActivity.this,REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("debinf MainAct", "response ERROR: "+error.networkResponse.allHeaders);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Use `REQUEST_CODE` sent by **startPayment** to obtain the checkout result in **onActivityResult**.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == MercadoPagoCheckout.PAYMENT_RESULT_CODE) {
            final Payment payment = (Payment) data.getSerializableExtra(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_PAYMENT_RESULT);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mp_results)).setText("Resultado del pago: " + payment.getStatus());
            //Done!
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null
                && data.getExtras().containsKey(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_ERROR)) {
                final MercadoPagoError mercadoPagoError =
                    (MercadoPagoError) data.getSerializableExtra(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_ERROR);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mp_results)).setText("Error: " +  mercadoPagoError.getMessage());
                //Resolve error in checkout
            } else {
                //Resolve canceled checkout
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's it! Please, be free to improve the above code. Mainly, regarding to the security issues.

Comment: Is there a way to send cardNumber and another information about credit card to mercadopago?

Comment: I'm implement this code but I get this error

NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=TEST-XXXXX


can you help ?

Comment: @exequielc I suspect it is Volley' server error exception as commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35426721/4300670). I think you need to trace the correct error.

Answer (score 1):

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val strJson = "{\n" +
            "           \"items\": [\n" +
            "               {\n" +
            "               \"title\": \"Item\",\n" +
            "               \"description\": \"Multicolor Item\",\n" +
            "               \"quantity\": 1,\n" +
            "               \"currency_id\": \"BRL\",\n" +
            "               \"unit_price\": 35.0\n" +
            "               }\n" +
            "           ],\n" +
            "           \"payer\": {\n" +
            "\t\t    \"name\": \"Núbia\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"surname\": \"Macedo\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"email\": \"leann@gmail.com\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"date_created\": \"2015-06-02T12:58:41.425-04:00\",\n" +
            "\t\t    \"phone\": {\n" +
            "\t\t      \"area_code\": \"\",\n" +
            "\t\t      \"number\": \"880.402.7555\"\n" +
            "\t\t    },\n" +
            "\t\t    \"identification\": {\n" +
            "\t\t      \"type\": \"DNI\",\n" +
            "\t\t      \"number\": \"123456789\"\n" +
            "\t\t    },\n" +
            "\t\t    \"address\": {\n" +
            "\t\t      \"street_name\": \"Núbia Viela\",\n" +
            "\t\t      \"street_number\": 25598,\n" +
            "\t\t      \"zip_code\": \"8972\"\n" +
            "\t\t    }\n" +
            "\t\t  }\n" +
            "     }"

    val obj = JSONObject(strJson)

    //val url = "https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences"
    val url = "https://api.mercadopago.com/checkout/preferences?access_token=TEST-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    val stringRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, url, obj,
        Response.Listener<JSONObject> {response ->
            val checkoutPreferenceId: String= response.getString("id")
            MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder("TEST-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX", checkoutPreferenceId)
                .build().startPayment(this, REQUEST_CODE)
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            val erros = error.toString()
            val teste1 = "sdsds"
            val teste12 = "sdsds"
            val teste13 = "sdsds"
        }

    ) {
        @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
            val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
            return headers
        }

    }

    val policy = DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 10, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
    stringRequest.retryPolicy = policy
    queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Do not forget to swap your access_token.

Json example: https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/payments/web-checkout/personalization/

packages:

```
implementation 'com.mercadopago.android.px:checkout:4.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Comment: The presented solution requires a previous knowledge which I lack, unfortunately. Please, could you expand your solution in a way that even a beginner could understand? I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: I'm using native android in Kotlin and Volley. Do you know how to use Volley?

Comment: As far as I could understand, volley is simple to use. We just need to provide an URL and JSON object. I am still trying to concatenate your solution with Android Java.

Comment: You can use another api for POST. Just need to pay attention to "Content-Type"="application/json" in Headers.

Comment: which Volley's method are you using? e.g: `StringRequest`, `JsonObjectRequest`.