# VOLLEY ERROR : Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send JSON using POST. But I am getting the following error.

**Volley: NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for "URL"**

I don't understand the issue. If I'm doing anything wrong in the below code, please let me know. Thank you.

```
private void postDataUsingVolley(String dev_id, String payload_raw) {

    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

        params.put("dev_id", dev_id);
        params.put("port", "1");
        params.put("confirmed", "false");
        params.put("payload_raw", payload_raw);
        params.put("schedule", "replace");

        final String mRequestBody = params.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, DOWNLINK_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {

                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Response code 400 means, [HTTP 400 Bad request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). There seems to be a problem with volley, when server responds with non 200 response. Volley throws this exception. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of StringRequest make a JsonObjectRequest directly, put your data in a JSON object and send the request to the network.

Like this:-

```
private void postDataUsingVolley(String dev_id, String payload_raw) {

JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
try {
    params.put("dev_id", dev_id);
    params.put("port", "1");
    params.put("confirmed", "false");
    params.put("payload_raw", payload_raw);
    params.put("schedule", "replace");
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, DOWNLINK_URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("Response", ""+response);

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());

    }
}) ;
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(request);
```

}