# 400 when using Deep AI API

Tags: java, android, android-volley

This is my code:

```
public void volleyPost(){
    String postUrl = "https://api.deepai.org/api/image-similarity";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postData.put("image1", "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/ct_snowwhite_upcportalreskin_20694_eb571c22.jpeg");
        postData.put("image2", "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41YWS0WYAJL._AC_SY780_.jpg");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, postData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("api-key", apiKey);
            headers.put("Accept","application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

And I get this error message:

```
E/Volley: [956] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.deepai.org/api/image-similarity
W/System.err: com.android.volley.ClientError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:199)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

Any idea?

Comment: The nested anonymous classes make this code very difficult to read. I suggest untangling this by using more variables. For example: `Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener = new Response.Listener<>() { ... };`. Then `JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postUrl, postData responseListener);`. You can similarly use variables for each of the other anonymous classes to make your code much more readable.

Comment: Maybe if you could add reference to your api documentation, it's hard to know what you're getting wrong when we don't know exactly what your api is expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add content-type to the header:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```

See this : [Android Volley - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796965/android-volley-basicnetwork-performrequest-unexpected-response-code-400)

Comment: Did not solve for me, but tnx.